# Rails 3.2.8 - Should I use Thread when I save multiple data into database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, thread-safety

I'm using Thread quite often and I wonder if this is a good practice:

```
    def self.create_all_posts
      threads = []
      self.fetch_all_posts.each do |e|
        if e.present?
          threads << Thread.new {
          self.create(title: e[:title], url: e[:url])
          }
        end
      end
        main     = Thread.main       # The main thread
        current  = Thread.current    # The current thread
        all      = Thread.list       # All threads still running

        all.each { |t| t.join }
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes. You might need to call config.threadsafe! in the application.rb and mayve allow_concurrency: true in the database.yml. Depending on your rails version you might needat least first one, otherwise your db request maight not run in parallel.

Still, in your case there might be no big performance effect on running everal "INSERT INTO..." in parallel, thought it heavily depend on your disks, memory and CPU situation on db host. BTW, if your fetch_all_posts takes considerable time to fetch, you can use find_each approach, that possible would start creation threads in parallel of scnning huge data set. You can set the 'page' size for find_each to make it run theads, say, on every 10 posts.